# Email sending in php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have to send email in php using jquery but the problem is when i click submit button and if the captcha is correct, it shows the message in alert box ("invalid mail") and Your Query has been received, We will contact you soon."; i really dont know how if else both are executed at same time. if the captcha is not correct, it shows invalid mail and invalid captcha..any one help me to fix this is issue.?

Email.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$email = '';

$json = array();

if (isset($_POST['Name']))
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
if (isset($_POST['Email']))
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
if (isset($_POST['Message']))
    $message = $_POST['Message'];

$subject = 'Enquiry';
//   $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    //echo filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);exit;

    if ($_SESSION['add'] == $_POST['captcha']) {


        $subject = $subject;

        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:' . $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
        $headers .= 'Cc:' . $email . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
        $template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:white;">Hello ' . $name . ',<br/>'
            . '<br/>Thank you...! For Contacting Us.<br/><br/>'
            . 'Name:' . $name . '<br/>'
            . 'Email:' . $email . '<br/>'

            . 'Message:' . $message . '<br/><br/>'
            . 'This is a Contact Confirmation mail.'
            . '<br/>'
            . 'We Will contact You as soon as possible .</div>';
        $sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#7E7E7E; color:white;\">" . $template . "</div>";

        $sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);

        //mail(Configure::read('__general_enquiries'), $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
        mail('balaji@ramsol.in', $message, $sendmessage, $headers);
        $json['success'] = "Your Query has been received, We will contact you soon.";

    } else {
        //$this->Session->setFlash(_('Invalid Captcha'));

        $json['error'] = "Invalid CAPTCHA";
    }
} else {
    $json['error'] = "Invalid Email";


}
echo json_encode($json);
exit;

//header('location:index.php');
?>
```

script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();
            var captcha = $("#captcha").val();

            $("#returnmessage").empty();

            if (name == '' || email == '' || message == '' || captcha == '') {
                alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
            }

            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'email.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {'name': name, 'email': email, 'message': message, 'captcha': captcha},
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data.success) {
                            alert(data.success);
                            $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
                        } else {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }
                    }

                    //window.location.href = "index.php";
                });
            }
        });
```

session code:

```
<?php 

//if(isset($_SESSION)){
session_start();    
$rand = rand(1,9);
$rand1 = rand(1,9);
 $rand =$_SESSION['rand'] = $rand;
 $rand1 =$_SESSION['rand1'] = $rand1;
 $_SESSION['add'] = $rand + $rand1;

?>
```

html code:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="email.php">
            <div class="form-group-inner">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="Email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="Message"  id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group-inner">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5 align="right" style="color: white;"><?php echo $_SESSION['rand']; ?> + <?php echo $_SESSION['rand1'];?></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="captcha" id = "captcha" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Here" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-action">
                <button type="submit" class="button-btn" name="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
            </div>  
        </form>
```

Comment: Provide and your html code?

Comment: just now added..

Comment: How you got both responses, when I execute your code it returns me `{"success":"Your Query has been received, We will contact you soon."}`

Comment: 1st invalid mail shows in the alert box then the success statement executed

Comment: is success statement return in alert box????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first of all, you should stop submitting of your form, because you are using ajax:

You should change:

```
    $('#submit').click(function () {
```

to

```
    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
```

Second, you send data: `{'name': name, 'email': email, 'message': message, 'captcha': captcha},` with lower case, but in your php code you check with uppercase of first char:

```
if (isset($_POST['Name']))
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
if (isset($_POST['Email']))
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
if (isset($_POST['Message']))
    $message = $_POST['Message'];
```

**Final code:**

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var captcha = $("#captcha").val();

        $("#returnmessage").empty();

        if (name == '' || email == '' || message == '' || captcha == '') {
            alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
        }

        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'email.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {'name': name, 'email': email, 'message': message, 'captcha': captcha},
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.success) {
                        alert(data.success);
                        $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
                    } else {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }
                }

                //window.location.href = "index.php";
            });
        }
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$email = '';

$json = array();

if (isset($_POST['name']))
    $name = $_POST['name'];
if (isset($_POST['email']))
    $email = $_POST['email'];
if (isset($_POST['message']))
    $message = $_POST['message'];

$subject = 'Enquiry';
//   $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    //echo filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);exit;

    if ($_SESSION['add'] == $_POST['captcha']) {


        $subject = $subject;

        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:' . $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
        $headers .= 'Cc:' . $email . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
        $template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:white;">Hello ' . $name . ',<br/>'
            . '<br/>Thank you...! For Contacting Us.<br/><br/>'
            . 'Name:' . $name . '<br/>'
            . 'Email:' . $email . '<br/>'

            . 'Message:' . $message . '<br/><br/>'
            . 'This is a Contact Confirmation mail.'
            . '<br/>'
            . 'We Will contact You as soon as possible .</div>';
        $sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#7E7E7E; color:white;\">" . $template . "</div>";

        $sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);

        //mail(Configure::read('__general_enquiries'), $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
        mail('balaji@ramsol.in', $message, $sendmessage, $headers);
        $json['success'] = "Your Query has been received, We will contact you soon.";

    } else {
        //$this->Session->setFlash(_('Invalid Captcha'));

        $json['error'] = "Invalid CAPTCHA";
    }
} else {
    $json['error'] = "Invalid Email";


}
echo json_encode($json);
exit;

//header('location:index.php');
?>
```

The problem with your code comes from there, that you are post your form directly to PHP.

Comment: thank you .. it works perfectly ..but the result comes like a echo statement..but i need to come the result in alert box..can you help me?

Comment: It should not comes like an echo statement, can you provide some screenshot ? Also check for `var_dump` in your code ?